# Get rid of duplicate when use Case condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following query:

```
declare
Balance_Year_Sub1_cursor Reports.rep_type;
Date_Parameter date;
  BEGIN
Date_Parameter := '01-Apr-2017';

OPEN Gas_Balance_Year_Sub1_cursor FOR

select case when Date_Parameter <= (select max(month) from BALANCE_YEAR2) then 
(
   select sum(FLARE_MTD_KNM3) FLARE_MTD_KNM3 from BALANCE_YEAR2
   where (month between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR') and  LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(date_parameter,0))) 

) 
   else  
(    
  select NET_VOL_MTD_KNM3 from STREAM_D where code = 'FLARE' 
  and production_day = LAST_DAY(trunc(Date_Parameter))
) 
  end FLARE_MTD_KNM3 from BALANCE_YEAR2;


               :to_grid := Balance_Year_Sub1_cursor;
END;
/
```

The value it gives is ok but generate duplicates for the number of rows from BALANCE_YEAR2, how to get rid of them:

```
FLARE_MTD_KNM3 
86751.8733412651
86751.8733412651
86751.8733412651
86751.8733412651
86751.8733412651
```

Comment: @InnovaITve Solutions: thanks for correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case expression is selected from `BALANCE_YEAR2`, so you're going to get one row of output for every row in that table, whichever branch of the case you go through - the value in each row in the result set will be the same, either the sum from the second query against that same table, or the single net value from `STREAM_D`.

You could query the maximum month value separately and then use a simple `IF` check to decide which table to select query:

```
DECLARE
   Date_Parameter date;
   Max_Month date;
BEGIN
  Date_Parameter := DATE '2017-04-01';
  select max(month) into Max_month from BALANCE_YEAR2;

  IF Date_Parameter <= Max_month THEN
    OPEN :to_grid FOR
      select sum(FLARE_MTD_KNM3) FLARE_MTD_KNM3
      from BALANCE_YEAR2
      where month between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR')
        and LAST_DAY(date_parameter);
  ELSE
    OPEN :to_grid FOR
      select NET_VOL_MTD_KNM3
      from STREAM_D
      where code = 'FLARE' 
      and production_day = LAST_DAY(Date_Parameter);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

or you could include the maximum-month query in each branch of a union:

```
DECLARE
  Date_Parameter date;
BEGIN
  Date_Parameter := DATE '2017-04-01';

  OPEN :to_grid FOR
    select sum(FLARE_MTD_KNM3) FLARE_MTD_KNM3
    from BALANCE_YEAR2
    where month between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR')
      and LAST_DAY(date_parameter) 
    and Date_Parameter <= (select max(month) from BALANCE_YEAR2)
    union all
    select NET_VOL_MTD_KNM3
    from STREAM_D
    where code = 'FLARE' 
    and production_day = LAST_DAY(Date_Parameter)
    and Date_Parameter > (select max(month) from BALANCE_YEAR2);
END;
/
```

In both cases I've removed some unnecessary `add_months`/`trunc` calls, changed the fixed date allocation to use a date literal instead of relying on implicit conversion and your NLS settings, and opened the `to_grid` bind variable cursor directly instead of using an intermediate `report_type` (cursor, presumably) variable.

Comment: To Alex: Brilliant!! Thanks!!